# Fancytree activateKey setting focus then scrolling to top dependant on key

Tags: javascript, fancytree

I am finding that activateKey is not setting focus correctly depending on the key/node used. It is first setting focus but then scrolling back up to the top of the tree with the active/selected node not in view.

The fiddle below works as expected:
http://jsfiddle.net/op5ga0zf/2/

This fiddle scrolls back up to the top of the tree, the only difference is the key value being used in activateKey:
http://jsfiddle.net/op5ga0zf/3/

I get the same behaviour in all browsers, am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

```
$(function() {
  var $orgtree = $('#orgtree');
  $orgtree.fancytree({
    autoScroll: true,
    activate: function(event, data) {
      data.node.setSelected(!data.node.isSelected())
    },
    checkbox: true,
    extensions: ['filter'],
    filter: {
      autoExpand: true,
      counter: false,
      mode: "hide"
    },
    icon: false,
    init: function(event, data) {
      var key = $('#OrganisationID').val();
      if (key !== '') {
        data.tree.activateKey(key);
      }
    },
    select: function(event, data) {
      if (data.node.isSelected()) {
        $('#OrganisationID').val(data.node.key);
      } else {
        $('#OrganisationID').val("");
      }
    },
    selectMode: 1,
    source: treeData,
    tabindex: ""
  });

  $('#filter-orgtree').keyup(function() {
    $orgtree.fancytree("getTree").filterNodes($(this).val());
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a [bug](https://github.com/mar10/fancytree/issues/863) and will be fixed with release 2.30.